# Import Snap.py in PyPy

Tags: python, pypy

I am working with [Snap.Py](http://snap.stanford.edu/snappy/).
I was trying to improve my efficiency by using PyPy, but I fail to import Snap.Py package.

This is what I have done so far:

1. Used pip install snap
2. pypy setup.py install

I see that the file snap.py was loaded from pypy/site-packages.
But it fails to load the _sanp package.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "app_main.py", line 75, in
>   run_toplevel   File "main.py", line 4, in 
>       import snap   File "/usr/.../Documents/pypy/pypy/site-packages/snap.py", line 32, in
>   
>       _snap = swig_import_helper()
>   File "/usr/../Documents/pypy/pypy/site-packages/snap.py", line 24, in
>   swig_import_helper
>
> ```
> import _snap ImportError: No module named _snap
> ```

I can see the file _snap.so under lib-python, but for somereason it is not loaded by pypy

From the snap.py code I can see that the import is done through  imp.find_module. 
I tried to update the sys path with sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/.../pypy/pypy/lib-python')
but it didn't help.

What am I missing?

Comment: you may not get the performance you hope for by using PyPy instead of CPython if you're already using a c extension.  see http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#do-cpython-extension-modules-work-with-pypy

Answer (score 0):

A file named `_snap.so` cannot be created by running pypy; it must have been created by mistake by running CPython.  If it were created with pypy it would be called something like `_snap.pypy-23.so`.  The line `pypy setup.py install`, to run in the source code of the snap package, is what you need.  If it doesn't correctly create and install a `_snap.pypy-23.so` you'll need to review carefully what it outputs and why...

As mentioned by IfLoop, this would be running a CPython C extension module on PyPy, which "often" works (not always) but is slower than on CPython.  If you have performance troubles on CPython, and if most of the time is spent in this C extension module anyway, switching to PyPy will not help at all.  It would only help if this _snap module is not at all the performance-critical part.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using python 32 bit version which does not work with snap as it quoted here : 
[Snapy Download page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36836453/1972584)

> (Windows 32-bit packages or Python 32-bit will not work). Python 2.7.x can be downloaded from the Python Download page. **Make sure that you are using 64-bit Python 2.7.x packages**.

To solve the issue, try installing a 64 bit version from here: 
[Link to download python 2.7 64bit](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/)

somehow similar problem [is asked in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36836453/1972584)

Comment: More elaboration on the answer will be good for this old post.