# SNAP installation in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been trying to install SNAP (http://snap.stanford.edu/snappy/index.html) in Python 2.7.9. I followed the instructions at snap website for installation but unable to import snap package/module.
My system configuration is:
     Windows 7 - 64 bit
I'm getting error that DLL load failed %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
Sorry I couldn't upload screenshot of command prompt due stackoverflow policies as i'm new to this forum.
Please help me to solve this issue. I'm new to Python.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If there is DLL error only than you  can download and install the missing dll file from google and drop it into the installed folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using python 32 bit version which does not work with snap as it quoted here : 
[Snapy Download page](https://snap.stanford.edu/snappy/index.html#download)

> (Windows 32-bit packages or Python 32-bit will not work). Python 2.7.x can be downloaded from the Python Download page. **Make sure that you are using 64-bit Python 2.7.x packages**.

To solve the issue, try installing a 64 bit version from here: 
[Link to download python 2.7 64bit](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/)